# Sending certificates from 2 way ssl .net based client

Tags: .net, web-services, ssl, certificate

I am completely new to SSL concepts. I have been moving from zero to the point where I have figured the pieces but running out of time for research for my project to put the pieces together.

We have custom application which calls another web-service (which is going to switch to 2 w ssl) in two places. 
     A) From a custom hosted web-service based on .net
     B) Another from a standalone dll

The above meant nothing before, but from what I understand.

**We being client, needs to send certificate to the server which will begin to request a certificate and will be verified based on some identification information in the certificate and this involves:**

- Getting a signed certificate signed by third party which the target server will trust.

> No issues so far. I am using 64 bit encoded .cer file for all below cases? I also read about der format etc? does it matter?

- Accessing from file vs accessing from store

  I have tried to access the certificate both as a file(`X509Certificate Cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(@"C:\Test.cer");`) and from the store (as below (2)), but I have no idea which is better. The server will be a secured one (so no issues with a random theif stealing the certificate) but it looks like from file seems to be simple when deploying code (more probably store concept is confusing).

> what method is preferable give the case we have a secure server but
>   different types of applications?
>
> Will this method work when calling the webservice from another
>   webservice that we have (see A)? Just read there might be issue that
>   non-standalone/non-console application will not work this way?. Even
>   if it works is it OK to use the cert from file that a store? Does it
>   cause any issues in future or will using store be more efficient in
>   some ways?

- Installing the certificate.

> Where should I install this certificate ?

I just installed this on Third-Party Root Certification Authorities  store. I was able to extract this certificate through the standalone dll. But the piece of code I used to extract from store was

`X509Certificate2Collection CertCollection = store2.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "blahblahIamThumprintofC:\Test.cer", false);`

> Its an effort with not much help and in short time so I am not able
>   to gauge the effect of using stores and then probably missing the
>   existence of store in another server when deploying? Is this the best
>   store to store? is it a commonly available store across all windows
>   servers? Does this store good enough for the (A) custom webservice
>   case? I read the certificates need to be stored in machines and not as
>   user ? and will need to provide access to webservice account to store
>   and etc? [using certmgr.msc to view certificate ]

- IIS role -  the hosting server for webservice

Since the web service (hosted on IIS 6) is also going to call the other web service,

> will I need to configure IIS to do this ? or this should be handled
>   through code as well? I also have PKCS  # 7 format cert as well? Does this come into picture in the case of .net webservice we have (A)

I can try a lot of methods but I a bit overwhelmed with lot of information and almost nil help other than google and SE **(store vs file, userstore vs machinestore, standalone dll vs .net webservice, 64bit vs der vs pkc #7, code change vs IIS)**

and if you ask me did you even try the code from the .net webservice ? NOPE - thats next, but trying to get more clarity meanwhile.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I have just started trying to do something very similar and I am pretty lost.

Comment: yes, I did to some extent. Will try to update with the answer soon. @Jules999